# Is it possible to get RSS archive

Tags: rss, feed

I know that rss feeds is news...Is it possible to get rss feed's from yesterday or day before yesterday...(more exactly, archive of rss feeds).

Comment: What kind of RSS-feed? Are you talking about your own RSS-feed? What programming language are you using? etc...

Comment: I use python and I want to get archive of rss feeds from diferent newspaper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the server decides what posts to feed you.

Your RSS server might be configured to let you have more posts by supplying arguments to the feed url - but thats unlikely.